# Displacing a grid and replacing faces

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I'm trying to recreate an effect similar to the man vs machine Fly knit weaving animation (https://vimeo.com/162826208 around one minute in). I have broken it down to several effects:
- Displacing the base grid
- Animations at the edge of the displacments
- A seed location to drive the displacement and the animation
- random delays in the animations or slow animations

One big issue I run into is that when I generate a grid, I can't displace the mesh itself, but only the objects I would instance. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, but I just recently started with animation nodes.

The animations I figured out already, I think. A guy on youtube has a video about it, or I can run them with shape keys.

The biggest issue here seems to be displacing the base mesh from a seed location in a way that can also drive other meshes. So going outside of the nodes to dynamic painting hasn't been successful for me so far.

another thing would be creating the weave. I could do this with a texture. But I'm also looking at some splines. is it possible to replace the faces of the grid in such a way that they actually deform along with those faces. so not a particle in the middle of the face, but rather a replacement of the face that connects to the next one seamlessly?

Comment: I am not sure to completely understand what you want to do, could you add some screenshots of your current setup and explain a little bit more please? For the grid mesh, if you are using the grid mesh generator (which you should do), simply add a vector list math node to the output, this will offset the grid

Comment: Hi Pascal, I got so frustrated I deleted everything. I have a feeling Im missing something barely out of my grasp, doesnt normally happen :<.

- For the grid displacement can I drive this through a loop of some sort then, with a proximity setup?

- The second part, what Im basically looking for is a way to use animation nodes to create an effect similar to the Tissue addon (http://www.co-de-it.com/wordpress/code/blender-tissue). Basically the primitive is deformed according to the points of a plane. Every face on the grid will be replaced by this grid.

Comment: I think using animation-nodes in order to generate mesh is mostly not a good idea... The addon focuses on animating individual objects, although you can generate meshes. I'm pretty sure there is a good way to script this in an, but I have no idea how... I don't understand why you don't actually use the tissue addon... If you look for a flexible mesh-generative addon, take a look to the [sverchok](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok) addon